# Excel - Vlookup - Why is it used? Not clear from examples

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Have learnt the use of Vlookup but it's not clear from any example why it is used.  The examples I have seen required obtaining information that would be obvious just by looking down the sheet.

Can anyone give an example of when it could be used, and which would be an easier option of just scanning the sheet for the required information?  This would help understand its usefulness, otherwise it just seems like a lot of work, just to pull something which could be retrieved by looking.

Thanks

Comment: What if the sheet has 80,000 rows? Still want to "look down" it to find what you're looking for?

Comment: Newer Excel versions have 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns per worksheet. Approximately 7 columns by 40 rows of cells per A4 sized page, so that’s about 61356149 A4 pages.
So if you have a completely filled Excel sheet and you would take about 1 second / page to lookup the information, in worst case scenario you would need to spend 710 days to fetch the intended data.

Comment: well anything could be done just by looking, so might as well uninstall excel altogether

Comment: I realise my question might have seemed a bit dumb.  I was just hoping for more experienced people to give an example of when they use vlookup, or point to an example, because the examples in lessons were not very realistic.

Answer (score 1):

> The examples I have seen required obtaining information that would be obvious just by looking down the sheet.

That can be true, but it's not sure.

As it's mentioned in the comments and previous answers already, there can be too many information, so just looking up would be difficult; or there could be similar codes which are difficult to distinguish.

Or you may want to further use `VLOOKUP`'s result in your formula.

Or you just want to collect information from multiple locations.

...

Answer (score 1):

I often use `vlookup()` when I need to rearrange a list.

For example, I have a master username list like this:

[image: Example]

I also have a list from our IT department over which user is online at any given time, however they only list the users username:

[image: Online]

By using `vlookup` I can get the name and contact details of any of the accounts in seconds instead of having to see which user is offline, swap tabs and get that users name and contact details. For one user the time saved would be several seconds, but for 1000's of users the time saved would be hours.

So, to answer your question, YES you can do a `vlookup` search manually, but when dealing with large data-sets you can save hundreds of hours using a `vlookup`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I realise my question might have seemed a bit ignorant to some, but I was really looking for examples like you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why are you even using Excel in the first place? 
You can write numbers (and text) on a piece of paper. 
If you have some reason for putting them into a computer file,
you can use Notepad. 
You can do math by hand, or in your head if it’s easy,
or with the Calculator if it’s hard.

Comment: To think those people must have wasted all that time writing excel, quattro pro etc etc ... :)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question:(

Comment: @MátéJuhász read my answer above - that should help you...

Comment: It answers the question using [the Socratic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method), in which the teacher responds to a question with another question (or several) in order to guide the student’s thought processes to help them realize the answer.

Comment: @SolarMike: I've read it, my question is how THIS answer fits on the site.

Comment: @G-Man: yes, I see the intent, however I don't think this fits the idea of the site. I would have posted it as a comment.

Comment: Either I didn't make myself clear in the question or you misunderstood. I wasn't suggesting that Excel or any of its functions were pointless, I was commenting on how no examples that I'd seen, showed Vlookup being used in any way that made practical sense.  Thanks for answering anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I use vlookup to get student names from a list with the grades for their assignments based on student numbers that are 6 digits - not easy to spot when the list is not sorted by number...

I also use index & match for the same thing so I don't have to re-order the columns as vlookup only works to the right of its index column - avoiding offset...